# c stack variable corrupted

Tags: c, stack

I have read all question for this type of problem but I can't fix mine. 
The problem is that I use a function for reading data from  a file and I get this error:
"Stack around variable 'p' was corrupted"
This is the function

```
Firm readFirm(char* name)
{
FILE* file = NULL;
int i = 0;
Firm firm;
char line[100];
char* p[5] = {(char*)malloc(50)};

char tmp[50];
strcpy(tmp,name);
strcat(tmp,".txt");
file = fopen(tmp,"rb");

getline(file,line,100);
strcpy(firm.name,line);
getline(file,line,100);
strcpy(firm.EIK,line);
getline(file,line,100);
split(p,line," ");
for (i = 0 ; p[i] != NULL; i++)
    firm.price[i] = atoi(p[i]);
getline(file,line,100);

split(p,line,".");
firm.day = atoi(p[0]);
firm.month = atoi(p[1]);
firm.year = atoi(p[2]);
fclose(file);
return firm;

}
```

Please help because I don't know how to fix it!

This is the split function:

```
char ** split( char *result[], char *w, const char *delim)
{
int i=0;
char *p=NULL;
for(i=0, result[0]=NULL, p=strtok(w, delim); p!=NULL; p=strtok(NULL, delim), i++ )
{
       result[i]=p;
       result[i+1]=NULL;
}
return result;
}
```

Comment: what is `char* p[5] = {(char*)malloc(50)};` supposed to do?

Comment: This is a two dimensional array which I use it for the split function

Comment: what the heck is this: `char* p[5] = {(char*)malloc(50)};`, i think you wanted something like auto initializing the array, like `char arr[10] = {0};` this wont work, because for each location you need separate memory address.

Answer (score 5):

The declaration `char* p[5] = {(char*)malloc(50)};` has issues.  It causes `p[1]`, `p[2]`, `p[3]`, and `p[4]` to be initialized to garbage, most probably, not many would be NULL, which is what the loop tests for.

There are also problems with the use of `getline()`, most notably that the parameters are in the wrong order and not sufficiently indirected.

Comment: @George I think the OP really wants an array of `char*`.

Answer (score 1):

change the line:

```
char* p[5] = {(char*)malloc(50)};
```

to

```
char *p[5];
int i=0, n=5;

/* Allocate */ 
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
{
  p[i] = malloc (sizeof (char) * 50);
}

/* Do work */

/* Deallocate */

for (i=0; i<n; i++)
{
  free (p[i]);
}
```

**EDIT1:**

it looks like you wanted to achieve default assignment of the remaining locations like we can do with

```
char arr[10] = {0};
```

But in your case you have

```
char *p[5];
```

and for each location of `p` you need a separate memory location which needs to be individually assigned/allocated to and freed/deallocated from like above.

**EDIT2:**

In your split function you are doing a terrible thing. If you have allocated the memory for `p` in the main and then you pass it to the `split` function, then why are you *assigning* a pointer again into the `p` array elements. Each of the element of `p` points to an entire array (block of memory) which can be used to hold a string. So you should *copy* the part of the string into `p[i]` for some index `i`, with `strcpy`.

Also why are you returning the array? You have passed it as a pointer, and all the modifications you do to it in the function will persist after the return.

**EDIT3:**

Here is the modified split, made by applying minimum modifications to your code.

```
void split( char *result[], char *w, const char *delim)
{
    int i=0;
    char *p;

    for(i=0, p=strtok(w, delim); p!=NULL; p=strtok(NULL, delim), i++ )
    {
       strcpy (result[i], p);
    }
}
```

Here is a test main function:

```
int main (void)
{

  char arr[128] = "10.08.1989";
  char *p[5];
  int i, n = 5;

  for (i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    p[i] = malloc (sizeof (char) * 50);
  }

  split (p, arr, ".");

  printf ("%s\n", p[0]);
  printf ("%s\n", p[1]);
  printf ("%s\n", p[2]);


  for (i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    free (p[i]);
  }
  printf ("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The same problem. In this function I use the variable two times and when I allocate the 'p' and before use it again free the allocate memory the program crash very bad.

Comment: what do you want actually a dynamically allocated array of `char` type with length 50? or 5 such arrays, ie a 2D array line structure.

Comment: OK I have for an example this string "13.05.2009" and I have to split it in this 2D array "13","05","2009" with a delimiter "." and thats why I need 2D array.

Comment: then you need to allocate separate memory for each string if you are dynamically allocating the strings, like the example above.